# SQL Server 2005 - exclude rows with consecutive duplicate values in 1 field

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a source table with 2 fields, a date, and a status code. I need a query to remove duplicate consecutive status codes, keeping only the row with the first date of a different status. For example:

```
Date       Status 
10/02/2004   A
10/12/2004   B
10/14/2004   B
11/22/2004   C
11/23/2004   C
12/03/2004   C
03/05/2006   B
```

The desired result set would be:

```
10/02/2004   A
10/12/2004   B
11/22/2004   C
03/05/2006   B
```

The main problem is that all the grouping functions (GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER() OVER) don't seem to care about order, so in the example, all the "B" status records would be grouped together, which is incorrect, since the status changes from non-"B" to "B" two different times.

This problem is easy to solve using a cursor based loop to produce the result. Just remember the current value in a variable, and test each record as you loop. That works perfectly, but is dreadfully slow (over 20 minutes on real data).

This needs to run on SQL Server 2005 and later, so some newer windowing functions are not available. Is there a way to do this using a set-based query, that would presumably run much faster? It seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but maybe not. Other similar questions on SO seem to rely on additional ID or Sequence fields that we do not have available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason regular grouping doesn't help in this situation is because the grouping criteria needs to reference fields in 2 different records to determine if a group break should occur. Since SQL 2005 lags behind the newer versions, we don't have a lag function to look at the prior record's value. Instead, we need to do a self join to get access to the prior record. To do that, we need to create a temporary sequence field in a CTE using ROW_NUMBER(). Then use that generated sequence in the self join to look at the prior record. We end up with something like:

```
;WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT myDate,myStatus,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myDate) as seq
  FROM myTable )
SELECT tmp.* FROM tmp LEFT JOIN tmp t2 ON t2.seq = tmp.seq-1
WHERE t2.seq is null OR t2.myStatus!=tmp.myStatus
```

So, even though the original data doesn't have a sequence column, we can generate it on the fly in order to be able to find the prior record (if any) for any given other record using the self join. Then we get the desired result of selecting only the records where the status has changed from the prior record.